# add animation to show user that add goods to tabbar badge

Tags: iphone

I notice there are some app, when I tap a button, it will display an animation look likes something drop from the button to uitabbaritem, and badge of the uitabbaritem will increade.

I try to do smashing in my app, but no result

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/23234805389/unobtrusive-hints-of-joy) describing how to animate a view down to a tab bar item and what troubles you might encounter.